# jQuery PHP add multiple text boxes and send them via ajax to php using serialized form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

**EDIT**

Now I can see errors at the network tab:

> Notice: Undefined index: medication_id in C:\wamp64...\addMedInfo.php
>   on line 8

[image]

I created a form where I specify for one time the name of the medication and the expiry date, and then add all the medicines with the same name and the same expiry date,  but of course with a different barcode as shown in snippet below:

```js
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("button.clone").on("click", clone);
    $("button.remove").on("click", remove);

    $("#sub").on('submit', function()
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: '../php/addMedInfo.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: send_data.serialize(),
        dataType: 'TEXT',
        success:function(resp)
        {

        },
        error:function(resp)
        {
          console.log(resp);
        }
      })
    })
  });

  var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;

  function clone() {
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
    $(".rounded").find("#clonedInput1").clone().insertAfter(".clonedInput:last").attr("id", "clonedInput" +  (cloneIndex+1));
  }

  function remove() {
    $(".rounded").find(".clonedInput:last").remove();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 ">
    <form name="send_data">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="medication_id">Medication</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control select" name="medication_id" id="medication_id">
                <option value="select">Select</option>
                <?php foreach($getExecGetMedications as $res) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $res['med_id'] ?>"><?php echo $res['med_name'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </fieldset>
        <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="expiry_date">Expiry Date</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date">
            </fieldset>
        <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 rounded" style="background-color: #D3D3D3">
    <div class="row clonedInput" id="clonedInput1">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="barcode">barcode</label>
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" id="barcode">
          </fieldset>
      <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="medication_quantity">Nbr of tablets</label>
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="medication_quantity" id="medication_quantity">
          </fieldset>
      <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="medication_pill">Nbr of Pills</label>
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="medication_pill" id="medication_pill">
          </fieldset>
      <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
      </div>
      <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="actions pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-danger clone">Add More</button> 
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button>
    </div>

  <!-- End class="col-sm-4" -->
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="Submit" id="sub">Submit</button> 
  </form>
```

Actually I can add as much as I need of text boxes so if I have 5 medications with the same name and expiry date, I can add 4 divs and then add the barcode with number of tablets and pills and click on sumbit button to send them to my database:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_error', 1);
require_once('../php/connection.php');

$clinic_id = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];

$medication_id = $_POST['medication_id'];
$expiry_date = $_POST['expiry_date'];
$barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
$medication_quantity = $_POST['medication_quantity'];
$medication_pill = $_POST['medication_pill'];

$addMed = "INSERT INTO med_pharmacy(med_id, med_barcode, med_received, med_expiry,
           med_tablet, med_pill, clinic_id)
           VALUES(:med_id, :med_barcode, :med_received, :med_expiry, :med_tablet, :med_pill, :clinic_id)";
$execAddMed = $conn->prepare($addMed);
$execAddMed->bindValue(':med_id', $medication_id);
$execAddMed->bindValue(':med_barcode', $barcode);
$execAddMed->bindValue(':med_received', now('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$execAddMed->bindValue(':med_expiry', $expiry_date);
$execAddMed->bindValue(':med_tablet', $medication_quantity);
$execAddMed->bindValue(':med_pill', $medication_pill);
$execAddMed->bindValue(':clinic_id', $clinic_id);
$execAddMed->execute();
?>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The problem now is that when I click on submit button, nothing happens, nothing added to database and no errors displayed at the console and at the network tab of the dev tools.

Comment: Your submit button must be inside `<form>`

Comment: As you can see it is inside the form, but anyway I changed it's position to the top but it didn't work as well

Comment: Ah I see, you have 2 `</form>` in your code, remove the top one

Comment: I removed and still the same

Comment: no there is not another form

Comment: Please all see my edits at the top of my question

Answer (score 0):

I have restructured your html a bit because it wasn't structured right. There were some incorrect placed closing div tags.

I also assigned an ID to your form which is called in javascript `on submit` instead of the ID of the button `sub`.

In the `data` parameter you assigned `send_data`, this is not the right parameter. You need the data of the form, so I changed it to `$(this).serialize()`.

As you can see in my snippet I logged the data that is being sent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.clone").on("click", clone);
  $("button.remove").on("click", remove);

  $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log("Fire request!");
    console.log($(this).serialize());
    e.preventDefault(); // Remove this line in production, just for demonstration purpose
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/addMedInfo.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'TEXT',
      success: function(resp) {

      },
      error: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      }
    })
  })
});

var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;

function clone() {
  var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
  $(".rounded").find("#clonedInput1").clone().insertAfter(".clonedInput:last").attr("id", "clonedInput" + (cloneIndex + 1));
}

function remove() {
  $(".rounded").find(".clonedInput:last").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-sm-12 ">
    <form name="send_data" id="form">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="medication_id">Medication</label>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control select" name="medication_id" id="medication_id">
                <option value="select">Select</option>
                <?php foreach($getExecGetMedications as $res) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $res['med_id'] ?>"><?php echo $res['med_name'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="expiry_date">Expiry Date</label>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date">
        </fieldset>
        <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 rounded" style="background-color: #D3D3D3">
        <div class="row clonedInput" id="clonedInput1">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="barcode">barcode</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" id="barcode">
            </fieldset>
            <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="medication_quantity">Nbr of tablets</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="medication_quantity" id="medication_quantity">
            </fieldset>
            <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="medication_pill">Nbr of Pills</label>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="medication_pill" id="medication_pill">
            </fieldset>
            <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
          </div>
          <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="actions pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-danger clone">Add More</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still having the errors that I posted at the top of my question 2 minutes ago. The PHP file cannot read the values of each array, and each array is not added as a row

Comment: You need to check in php if the variables are actually set before inserting them in the database

Comment: they actually are set

Comment: That's weird because those errors occur when you're trying to access an undefined index

Comment: Can you see the PHP script that I've added in my question ?

Comment: Yes, check if the `$_SESSION` variables are set before assigning them to a variable.

Comment: yes this the only variable that I didn't get an error about